# Make button & list in listview clickable

Tags: android, listview

I have a list view which I've successfully made the list itself to be clickable. Now inside the list, I also have a button. I've tried numerous ways but I can't get the button to be clickable. Here's how my list looks like

```
========================================
content 1               [button remove]
========================================
content 2               [button remove]
========================================
content 3               [button remove]
========================================
```

I can make the contents (eg: content 1, content 2) clickable; I've successfully opened a dialog box when clicking on the contents itself. Now I want to make the [button remove] clickable too, which should trigger a toast. However no matter what I tried, it seems I can't get my app to detect that button remove have been clicked.

Here's a portion of my code:
mylist.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="4dip">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.4"
        android:id="@+id/tvDescription" />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="0dip"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.1"
        android:id="@+id/tvRating" />

    <Button
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Remove"
        android:focusable="false"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:id="@+id/btnRemoveExpenses" />


</LinearLayout>
```

daily.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingTop="50dip"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:id="@+id/ll_expensesDaily"
    android:baselineAligned="false">
    <ListView
            android:id="@android:id/list"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

MyOwnList.java

```
    private ListView lvExpenses;
public class MyOwnList extends Fragment{
     @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState){
        final View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.daily, container, false);

lvExpenses = (ListView) rootView.findViewById(android.R.id.list);
         lvExpenses.setItemsCanFocus(true);
lvExpenses.setOnItemClickListener(expensesClickHandler);
return rootView;
}

private AdapterView.OnItemClickListener expensesClickHandler = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView parent, View v, int position, long id)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), " i: " + position + " long: " + id, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            showEditExpensesDialog(expensesID.get(position));
        }
    };
}
```

Comment: @miav if I did that, the list view couldn't even be selected/clicked

Comment: Where did you define button's `onClick()`?

Comment: @user370305 nowhere. I thought the OnItemCLickListener should handle that?

Comment: Nope, You have to define `onClick()` for your button. In its Custom adapter of ListView.

Comment: You might want to take a read [here](http://wiresareobsolete.com/2011/08/clickable-zones-in-listview-items/).

Comment: Try to add onClickListener to your button in Adapter

Answer (score 0):

Add an on click listener to the button in your adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I would ignore the on item click listener and do it in the xml.

Add to the button: android:onClick="removeBtnClicked"

Add to the code of the activity:

```
public void removeBtnClicked(View v){
   //Do something in here to remove row / set the row visibility to gone
}
```